# Cisco phone system auto attendant dial-by-name feature cannot find one particular person

Tags: cisco, voip, telephony

There is one individual here whose name cannot be found when a caller uses the "dial-by-name" function in the auto attendant of our Cisco Unified Communications phone system.  As far as I can tell from comparing the configuration of other users' directory listings there's nothing different for this user.

I don't want to have to remove and re-add him.  Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does this user show up in the directory when you search for them on the Cisco phone by selecting the Directory button -> Corporate Directory option? If they do not I would first check that users voice mail account as the Auto Attendant and Dial-by-name features are, in a typical deployment, handled by the Voice mail/Unity box.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Very strange.

Under "**Line Settings for this Device**", I added his four digit extension to the "**Line Text Label**", clicked "**Update**", and now it works.

Mind you not everyone has a value here, though some do. I figure the record for this user in the directory must've been corrupted or something, and putting in a new value and resubmitting fixed it.

Seems logical, I guess